# Did I code this correctly? WHat can I do to fix these errors?

Tags: java

I have a class created called "grade." My instructions say the class needs 3 methods and 2 constructors. The 3 methods I am to use are

- `"public void setNumber(int number)"`
- `"public int getNumber()"`
- `"public String getLetter()"`

The  first constructor should accept no parameters and set the initial value of the number instance variable to zero. The second should accept an integer value and use it to set the initial value of the number instance variable. In the `getLetter()` method, I have a warning that says "assignment to itself." I also have an error at the end that says "missing return statement." What corrections can I make? How can I fix these errors? The code I have is below.

```
public class Grade {

private int number;
private String letterGrade;

public void setNumber(int number) {
this.number = number;

}

public int getNumber() { 
return number; 

}
public String getLetter() {
    this.letterGrade = letterGrade;

}
}
```

Comment: `getLetter` needs to return the data.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared doesn't have any constructors but you have mentioned you'll need to use 2 constructors (Default constructor and Parameterized constructor). You can refer to code below to do what you've explained in the question.

```
public class Grade {

    private int number;
    private String letterGrade;

    //2 constructors as mentioned in question
    Grade() {
        this.number = 0;
        this.letterGrade = ""; //initialize to default value you decide upon
    }
    Grade(int n) {
        this.number = n;
        this.letterGrade = "sample"; //initialize to default value you decide upon
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public String getLetter() {
        //this.letterGrade = letterGrade; // "assignment to itself" error thrown because you are not passing
                                          // letterGrade as an argument to set the value to data-member
        return this.letterGrade;          // "missing return statement" error thrown as you missed return statement.
    }

    /* this is correct if choose to do so
    public String getLetter(String letterGrade ) {
        this.letterGrade = letterGrade ;
        return this.letterGrade;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, none of these methods are **constructors**, a constructors has no return type specification **and** also has the same name of the class. Second, the problem with `getLetter()` is that in it's context, there's no `letterGrade` and neither a `letterGrade` variable being passed as an argument, so the compiler checks the context of the `Grade` class and determines there is a variable with that name, so it assumes that the line `this.letterGrade = letterGrade;` is assigning itself's itself value, an self-assignment. Here's the corrected code for your class

```
   public class Grade {

    private int number;
    private String letterGrade;

    public Grade()
    {
      number = 0; //an int is 0 by default, this is not neccessary.
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() { 
         return number; 

    }
    public String getLetter() {
        return letterGrade;

    }
}
```